# Translate String Representation of Enum Values Qt

Tags: c++, qt, enums, translation

Is it possible to translate the string representation of an `enum` (i.e. via `QMetaEnum`) using Qt's translation system?

What I think I need is for some way to get `lupdate` to pick up the enum strings for translation, either by emitting some QT_TR_NOOP() code if and only if the file is being processed by lupdate, or by modifying the behavior of `lupdate`/`moc` themselves.

For example, my application presents "settings" options to users via a dialog box.  All of the settings are defined as `Q_PROPERTY` 's.  Options which use an `enum` are presented as a combo box and the text options for the combo box use the `QMetaEnum::key()` as the displayed text.  Below is some pseudo-code to get the point across.

Widgets will have some `enum` property defined like:

```
class SomeWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS( Configuration );

    enum Configuration
    {
        Config_Blue = 0,
        Config_Green,
        Config_Invisible,
        Config_Backwards
    };

    Q_PROPERTY( Configuration READ Configuration WRITE SetConfiguration );
};
```

The combo widget creation is done by a separate settings manager and goes something like this:

```
QWidget* SettingsItem::CreateWidget()
{
    const QMetaObject* pMetaObj = this->m_pWidget->metaObject();
    const QMetaProperty& rcProp = pMetaObj->property( this->m_iProp );

    QMetaEnum cEnum = rcProp.enumerator();
    if( cEnum.isValid() )
    {
        QComboBox* pRetWidget = new QComboBox;
        for( int i = 0; i < cEnum.keyCount(); ++i )
        {
            int iVal = cEnum.value( i );
            QString strKey = cEnum.key( i );  // Translate here?
            pRetWidget->addItem( strKey, iVal );
        }
    } 

    ...
    return pRetWidget;
}
```

The combo box in the settings dialog shows "Config_Blue", "Config_Green", etc.  I would like it to just say "Blue", "Green", etc. in whatever the current language is.

For the rest of the code we use Qt's translation system and the `linguist` utility which works really nice.  I was hoping that I could enable this type of translation for the `enum` 's as well without having to add string literals and `tr()` 's into the code manually.  Basically all of the information that a translator would need is already there in the code, I just need `linguist` to be able to identify these enum values as translatable.  I can then invoke `tr()` when the combo box is populated.

What I think I need is for some way to get `lupdate` to pick up the enum strings for translation, either by emitting some QT_TR_NOOP() code if and only if the file is being processed by lupdate, or by modifying the behavior of `lupdate`/`moc` themselves.

I was thinking maybe a macro would work, might not be possible though.  Perhaps modifying some Qt code is necessary?

Comment: I initially wanted to write a reply but I myself read about it from: http://kalebpederson.com/index.php/2010/07/qmetaenum-magic-serializing-c-enums

Comment: This just seems to describe how to use QMetaEnum to get the key values as string.  I believe this is what I am already doing.  What I really need I guess is for those enum strings to be picked-up by lupdate so that they can be translated.  Maybe I will revise my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum identifier shouldn't be user-visible to begin with. These are identifiers that should be meaningful to the developer, not to the user. Exposing them directly to the user adds a strong coupling between the internal design of the code and user-visible behavior. That is best avoided.

You need to map between enum values and user-visible strings. The values in the map should be subject to translation, and the map should be re-populated upon retranslation. E.g.:

```
class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(Configuration);
    Q_PROPERTY(Configuration READ Configuration WRITE SetConfiguration);

    enum Configuration {
        Config_Blue, Config_Green, Config_Invisible, Config_Backwards
    };
public:
    static QString toString(Configuration c) {
      switch (c) {
      case Config_Blue: return tr("Blue", "Configuration");
      case Config_Green: return tr("Green", "Configuration");
      case Config_Invisible: return tr("Invisible", "Configuration");
      case Config_Backwards: return tr("Backwards", "Configuration");
      }
    }
};
```

You can now translate the configuration values.

Comment: If I have 700 options in the form of various enums, I should write this type of switch for all of them

Comment: Yes, you should, because **all of them** are user facing strings. C++ identifiers are not really something that makes sense to users. There's no way to punctuate them properly, etc. You pretty much messed up in your design by depending on user-visible identifiers. You have to fix the mess you've found yourself in. Perhaps all of this will make you realize *how much work you've made yourself do*. You have 700 translatable strings. Are you sure your configuration system is not a bit overboard?

Comment: I don't actually have 700 options, I picked a number.  How would one correct this design that I messed up?

Comment: By doing what I show in the answer instead of what you do in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a dedicated function within the class in which I define my enum. Is it helpful? (Qt5.13).

I call it like MyClass::toTrString(myEnumVal);

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    enum MyEnum {
            myKey1,
            myKey2,
            ...
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
    static QString toTrString(MyEnum t) {
        return tr(qPrintable(QVariant::fromValue(t).toString()));
    }
}
```